# Is the rate of rotation the same between points in a plane?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

Assume a body rotating around (the z-axis in) a point in a (x-y) plane. I.e. the point of rotation could be outside the body. If you measure or calculate the turn rate in any point on the plane would you get the same values (rad/s)?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, rotational velocity is *shared* by all points on the body, and even the extended body (frame).

Rotational velocity is a vector that does not change value with position, unlike translational velocity. It is this quality exactly that makes it a more fundamental concept of motion. You can always derive translational velocity from angular velocity and position.

Additionally, rotation isn't a property of any point. Points don't rotate, they only translate. Only the collective rigid body is said to have rotation. Rotation is a property of *the entire body* and velocity is a property of a single point.